# How to get <td> values from the table for onclick <tr>?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

As you can look through my fiddle, i want if i click on the `Po` button i want the values of that row ? same apply for the `capax` .

[MYFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gwZG6/#&togetherjs=aF0vteafbq)

Comment: So you basically came up with nothing, have nothing to post, and never made an attempt to figure it out ?

Comment: i have saw many question related to this but did not get any thing

Comment: What value? Can you be more specific?

Comment: `1234` are the elements of `td` then if i click on `4` i want output as `123`